# Convergence in Product Topology (Example)

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $f_n \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ with

$f_n(x):=|x|^n$ for $0 \leq |x| \leq$ 1

$f_n(x):= \frac{1}{|x|^n}$ for $1< |x|$

Does $f_n(x)$ konverge? If yes, to which function?

What I know:

for $f_n \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}} : (f_n \ f) \Leftrightarrow (\forall x \in R: f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x))$

I would say $f_n$ does converge.

For $|x| \neq1 f_n \rightarrow 0_f$

($0_f$ is the zero-function)

for
$x=1$ and $x=-1$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x|^n=1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

So $f_n$ converges to the function

$f(x)=0$ for $|x| \neq 1$

$f(x)=1$ for $|x| = 1$

Question:
Are my calculations correct?
The way convergence works in the product topology $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ looks alot like the "pointwise convergence" I got to know in analysis. Are they kind of familiar or am I  misunderstanding something?

Comment: Convergence in product topology is same as point-wise convergence. What you have done is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Convergence in the product topology is indeed the same as pointwise convergence i.e.

$$f_n \to f \iff \forall x \in \Bbb R: f_n(x) \to f(x)$$

(this also holds for nets and then uniquely characterises the product topology).

So what you've done is correct and the limit is

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{ if } |x| \neq 1\\
        1 & \text{ if } |x| = 1 \\
\end{cases}$$